# How to apply Jquery Chaining to Multiple Parents method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need filter course details according to level and semester selectors value..We try it using [Chaining to Multiple Parents](http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects)

(One child can also have two parents. Available options on child chained to multiple parents depend on one or both of the parents selected values)

here code that we try (remove all Chained Selects codes,to get clear idea)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.chained.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <select name="level" id="level_id">
                 <option value="level-1">Level 1</option>
                 <option value="level-2">Level 2</option>
                 <option value="level-3">Level 3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="semester" id="semester_id">
                 <option value="semester-1">Semester 1</option>
                 <option value="semester-2">Semester 2</option>
     </select>


     <select name="course" id="course_id">
                 <option value="1">Multimedia</option>
                 <option value="10">Botany Practicals II</option>
                 <option value="9">Genetics</option>
                 <option value="4">Plant Diversity Unity & Evolution</option>
                 <option value="6">Plant Anatomy</option>
                 <option value="5">Scientific Approach & Biometrics</option>
                 <option value="11">Advanced Ecology</option>
                 <option value="12">Advanced Plant Pathology </option>
                 <option value="7">Advanced Microbiology</option>
                 <option value="8">Economic Botany</option>
                 <option value="13">Cropping System</option>
                 <option value="14">Food Technology</option>
     </select>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here how course will be filter according to the level and semester
[image]

But unable to understand how to apply that code.Please help us..

Jquery Code: [Jquery](http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.chained.js)

Comment: Can you paste the actual Javascript code as well? I think it should be in `jquery.chained.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chain the select with their id

```
$("#course_id").chained("#level_id, #semester_id");
```

---

**EDIT :** added a test fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/VwuvY/ .

**EDIT 2 :** in order to get the filter on 2 preceding lists, the class should be composed of the 2 values separated by a `\` (for example, for first semester and first level, the class should be `level-1\semester-1` . Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/VwuvY/1 .

Comment: Problem is how to apply class details,this plugin has patten how to apply..

example:-Main drop down value used as second drop down class value

Don't know how will course dropdown class value apply

Comment: I have added a fiddle in order to show how to apply classes : in fact the classes that you have to apply are the values from the "parent" selects.

Comment: Friend filter working for only level select.first select level and then select semester,it's not filtering with semester..

Comment: Oh sorry yes, you have to separate the 2 values by a `\` instead of a space. Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/VwuvY/1/ .

Comment: Thanks @SamuelCaillerie! This little piece of code saved me a lot of time. I've forked it and made an option for a "Other" input text box. http://jsfiddle.net/hireconor/cv5s5/